# How to change default values after initialising plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i am trying to create a plugin using the code below.

Basically the plugin is a calendar that lives inside **calendar.js**

What i can't figure out is how can i create next and previous buttons to change between months and the positions of days?

here is the plugin code

```
var Calendar = Calendar || (function(){


  return {
    init: function(args) {
      _args = args; //arguments array

      var Months = new Array( "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June" , "July" , "August" ,"September" ,
                              "October" , "November" , "December" ) ;

      var daysMonth = new Array(31 , 28 , 31 , 30 , 31 , 30 , 31 , 31 , 30 , 31 , 30 , 31 ) ;

      var theDays   = new Array( "Sunday" , "Monday" , "Tuesday" , "Wednesday" , "Thursday" , "Friday" , "Saturday") ;

      var leapYear = function (year){
        if (year % 4 == 0 || (year % 100 == 0 && year % 400 == 0)){
          length = 29;
        }else{
          length = 28;
        }
        return length;
      }

      var today = new Date(); // whole date including the hour
      var date = today.getDate(); // returns the date only e.g 15 (of August)
      var month = Months[today.getMonth()]; // returns month name after it gets month number
      var year = today.getFullYear(); // returns year

      // check february if it has 28 or 29 days
      if (today.getMonth() == 1){
        daysMonth[1] = leapYear(year);
      }

      // get the day place in the week
      today.setDate(1);
      var dayOfWeek = today.getDay();

      // get total cells number
      var howManyCells = daysMonth[today.getMonth()] + dayOfWeek ;

      function populateCalendar() {

       var content = "<TR>" ;

       for (var i= 1 ; i <= howManyCells ; i++) {
              if (i <= dayOfWeek  ) {
                 // cells prior to first day occurrence
                 content += "<TD><pre> </pre></TD>"
              }
              else {
                 // enter date number
                 content += "<TD align=center>" + (i - (dayOfWeek) ) + "</TD>"
              }
              // must start new row after each week
              if ( i % 7 == 0 &&  i != howManyCells ) {
                 content += "</TR><TR>"
              }

           }

           return content ;
        }
      var content = "<center><table border=3>" ;
       content     += "<tr><th COLSPAN=7>" + month + " " + ( today.getFullYear() ) + "</th></tr>"
       content     += "<tr><th>Sun</th><th>Mon</th><th>Tue</th><th>Wed</th><th>Thu</th><th>Fri</th><th>Sat</th></tr>"

       var content1 = populateCalendar() ;

       content     += content1 ;
       content += "</table></center>" ;

       document.write(content);
    }
  }
}());
```

and i initialise it like that and pass it parameters in an array like below. there are default values inside but those can be changed.

```
Calendar.init(["test"]);
```

Comment: `<center>` tag is deprecated and you sure don't want to use `document.write` in an interactive component

Comment: ok understood,what should i replace it with? any advice on my initial puzzling?

Comment: @PetrosKyriakou `document.write` should just be used for testing, use `element.innerHTML` or other similar methods. The `<center>` tag should be replaced with the CSS `margin:0 auto;`